# How to add custom measurements to iPhone Health App

Tags: health.app

I know how to add things like weight and BMI, but I would like to track custom fields/measurements as well. For example, my scale shows percentage of body water, but I cannot find this anywhere.

Is it possible at all to add fields to the Health App? Couldn't find it in the [support page](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/manually-add-data-iph6ccc2ded1/ios). Thanks.